# Angular ng-view access controller scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, scope

I'm trying to access a controller inside ng-view. [Routing & Multiple Views](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) suggests simply adding the controller as a parameter of the passed object. So I have:

**inside my app.config:**

```
$routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'ng-view/index.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    });
```

**the controller I'm trying to use:**

```
app.controller('HomeController', function($scope){
    $scope.hello = "something";
});
```

**ng-view/index.html:**

> {{hello}}

This gives me: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token h`

Now I know wrapping the variable in a div with ng-controller="homecontroller" works, but surely that defeats the point of passing the controller via the route provider?

Am I going about accessing the scope wrong?

Comment: Your example code is working fine, see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YypxSP5sw1uyVV0wgFQX?p=preview). The error might come from somewhere else.

Comment: Did you add the controller before you called the config block?

Comment: I've solved the problem, it was because I was using [[ ]] (posted as {{}} to leave out the interpolation declarations) Not sure why using [[]] instead of {{}} causes an error, however it works when wrapped with the controller.

Comment: @Klee provide full code